# Regex does not work as expected in interpreter

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to search through a string and find units in fahrenheit and convert them into celcius.

To do this, my approach is to user regex to find units in fahrenheit in a given string, and if I find any, get the number and convert it into celcius.

This is the regex I have come up with:

```
regexp = re.compile("\d+(.*?)(\bfahrenheit\b|\bf\b)", re.IGNORECASE)
```

[And here is the regex in action.](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cd%2b%28.%2a?%29%28%5Cbfahrenheit%5Cb%7C%5Cbf%5Cb%29&test_string=Preheat%20oven%20to%20350%C2%B0F%20%20Coat%2012%20muffin%20tin%20with%20low%20fat%20cooking%20spray%20or%20line%20with%20paper%20baking%20cups.%0AWarm%202%20Tbsp%20of%20oil%20in%20skillet%20over%20medium%20heat.%20%20Add%20bell%20pepper%20and%20cook%20,stirring,%20about%205%20minutes,%20until%20tender.%20%20Add%20green%20onions%20and%20cook,%20stirring%20for%201%20minute,%20or%20until%20softened.%20%20Remove%20from%20heat%20and%20place%20into%20small%20bowl.%20Let%20cool%205%20minutes.%0AIn%20a%20medium%20bowl,%20whisk%20together%20yogurt,%20egg,%20egg%20whites,%20sugar,%20chopped%20green%20chili%27s%20and%20the%201/4%20cup%20of%20oil.%20%20Fold%20in%20bell%20pepper%20mixture%20and%20corn.%20%20Fold%20into%20dry%20ingrediants%20until%20just%20moistened.%0ACool%20in%20pan%20on%20wire%20rack%20for%205%20minutes.%20%20Gently%20twist%20muffins%20in%20tin%20to%20loosen%20for%20easier%20removal.%20%20Remove%20from%20pan%20to%20cool%20completely%20%20on%20wire%20rack.&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

On the Pythex site it seems to work OK, however, in my interpreter the same regex does not match anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Notice that this matches more then you'd probably like. This matches `12 children received grades ranging from A to F`, all the way from '12' to 'F'. You may want to rethink that regex.

Comment: You're right. What would be the best approach to limit that from happening? Replacing the .*? with .{1,3}? for example? It's probably not the best approach, I know... I'm quite new to Regex, any suggestions would be more than welcome :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a raw string, or `\b` will mean "backspace" instead of "word boundary":

```
regexp = re.compile(r"\d+(.*?)(\bfahrenheit\b|\bf\b)", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd rewrite the regex to something like

```
regexp = re.compile(r"\d+\W{0,3}(f(ahrenheit)?)\b", re.IGNORECASE)
```

This matches 1 or more digits, followed by 0 to 3 non-word characters, followed by Fahrenheit — either as a letter F or the full name — which must be followed by a word boundary.

You still need the raw string for that final word boundary, but this string has a higher likelihood of matching what you want.
You can narrow the non-word characters down by using a character class, for instance `[\s°]`.

Comment: Cool! That also seems to solves you comment on my original question. Thanks!

Comment: @TimPietzcker True, but that opens up another can of worms. While we might want to allow for an optional space between the minus sign and the number, how do you want `270ºC - 64ºF` to be matched?